# Минимальное кол-во цифр в input tel

Tags: javascript

В таком коде отправляется input tel с +, нужно сделать минимальное кол-во символов для отправки номера. При клике на input tel вставляется автоматический + и дальше подключается маска со всеми номера разных стран и их длина. Как написать минимальное кол-во цифр после +? min и max в html не работают

```
const mask = (selector) => {
    function setMask() {
        let matrix = '+###############';

        maskList.forEach(item => {
            let code = item.code.replace(/[\s#]/g, ''),
                phone = this.value.replace(/[\s#-)(]/g, '');

            if (phone.includes(code)) {
                // console.log(phone, code);
                matrix = item.code;
            }
        });

        let i = 0,
            val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');

        this.value = matrix.replace(/(?!\+)./g, function(a) {
            return /[#\d]/.test(a) && i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i >= val.length ? '' : a;
        });
    }

    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    inputs.forEach(input => {
        // if (!input.value) input.value = '+';
        input.addEventListener('input', setMask);
        input.addEventListener('focus', setMask);
        input.addEventListener('blur', setMask);
    });
};
```

В отдельном файле maskList сотни авто номеров разных стран:

```
const maskList = [
    { "code": "+247 ####" },
    { "code": "+290 ####" },
    { "code": "+290 ####" },
    { "code": "+683 ####" },
    { "code": "+690 ####" },
    итд... ];
```

В основном js еще:

```
mask("[data-tel-input]");

// Del "+" placeholder

const phoneInputs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-tel-input]");
phoneInputs.forEach((input) =>{
  input.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
    if (input.value == "+") input.value = "";
  })
  input.addEventListener("blur", ()=>{
    if (input.value = "+") input.value = "";
  })
});
```

Html:

```
<label for="phone">Phone
  <input data-tel-input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number:" required>
</label>
```

Comment: У вас используется переменная maskList - но в коде нет ее объявления.
Так же нет самого input на котором висит обработчик. Так же, указанный код просто проставляет маску ввод в input но на "отправку" данных не влияет, как и не ограничивает по длине. Такую проверку надо делать вне данного кода